# Passing function down multiple children reactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, containers

I'm trying to build an application to help me learn react. It's a simple app that takes users input location, gets the coordinates from googles geolocation api and then gets the weather conditions for that location with dark skys api.

I originally had all my application logic in one container which you can see here https://github.com/darragh3277/night-sky

I want to separate out my logic a bit more to as I felt my one container was doing too many things. I'm looking to structure my app as follows.

App.js - Holds state, locationChangeHandler function to pass down to LocationSearchContainer.

LocationSearchContainer - Geolocation API and calls LocationSearch to display search bar

WeatherContainer - WeatherAPI and calls Weather component to render the display.

I believe this gives me a better separation of concerns and makes my code a bit more readable.

Because of this structure I think I need a locationChangeHandler in my App.js that will be passed to my Dump LocationSearch component. This tightly couples my App.js to the search bar but as that's the core function of the app I don't believe it's a problem.

What I'm having trouble with is how to pass my handler from App.js -> LocationSearchContainer -> LocationSearch. Here is my poor attempt so far:

In App.js I have

```
handleLocationChange = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
        console.log('hello');

        //Calls getLocation in LocationSearchContainer and updates state
}

render(){
    return (
            <LocationSearchContainer onLocationChange={this.handleLocationChange} />
    )
}
```

In LocationSearchContainer I have the following:

```
import React from 'react';
import LocationSearch from '../components/LocationSearch';


class LocationSearchContainer extends React.Component{

    getLocation = (address) => {

        //DO STUFF

    }

    render(){

        return (
            <LocationSearch onLocationChange={this.props.handleLocationChange} />
        )

    }

}

export default LocationSearchContainer;
```

And finally LocationSearch:

```
import React from 'react';

const LocationSearch = (
            <form onSubmit={props.onLocationChange}>
                <div className="input-group">
                    <input type="text" name="location" className="form-control" placeholder="Search location..." />
                    <button className="btn btn-primary">Go!</button>
                </div>
            </form>
)

export default LocationSearch;
```

How can I pass this handler down correctly?

Once I have the above working I'll also need to call the getLocation in my SearchLocationContainer from App.js but I'm not sure how to do that either?

**EDIT**

I've figure out part one of my problem. I was calling the function by name rather than the prop name I was passing. So in the render() function of my LocationSearchContainer I should have had

```
return (
        <LocationSearch onLocationChange={this.props.handleLocationChange} />
    )
```

rather than my original.

That still leaves me with the problem of calling my LocationSearchContainer's getCoordinates function from my App.js file. Anyone able to help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing your handler like that:

```
<LocationSearchContainer onLocationChange={this.handleLocationChange} />
```

So, in `LocationSearchContainer` component, your handler function's name is `onLocationChange`, within props it is `this.props.onLocationChange`.

So, you need to pass this function to your `LocationSearch` component like that:

```
<LocationSearch onLocationChange={this.props.onLocationChange} />
```

Lastly, you need to use it in `LocationSearch` as `props.onLocationChange`

For your second question, you shouldn't try to invoke a child component's method from the parent. Change your logic. Either keep this function in the parent, then pass it again as a prop to your child component or move the logic to your child component.

Comment: He could use refs to achieve the second part, although it would be a really bad practice lol

Comment: Bad indeed.. :)